# How to update to latest VirtualBox and backup files?

Tags: updates, virtualbox

I want to update to the latest version of VirtualBox. How can I do it without
losing the OS I installed and the files inside?  How can I backup everything 
I have on VirtualBox? I currently have VirtualBox 4.0.8 on a Windows 7 64-bit 
machine and I installed the latest version of Ubuntu on VirtualBox.

Comment: I've never had any data loss due to upgrading VirtualBox. Heck, the latest version (at least for Mac) is only 4.0.12 so what makes you think that you'll lose your VM?

Answer (score 3):

Similar question here

https://askubuntu.com/questions/19268/how-to-upgrade-virtualbox-to-the-latest-version

Technically you will  not lose your virtual machines by just upgrading vbox

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry, you won't loose your VMs (I just updated yesterday). If you really want, you could copy your VDI file (the one containing your hard drive) to another location as backup, and **in case** something goes wrong, you could make a new Ubuntu VM, and use your backed up VDI as your hard drive.